# Is there a way I can restrict my phone to connect to network I set only?

Tags: android, android-wifi

I want my android phone to connect to my office WIFI only or the WIFI that I choose. If I try to connect to any other WIFI by entering password it should not connect.

Is there a way to do this. If someone can share any idea about a custom APP to perform this task, that would also be helpful.

Thanks.